# Service Fabric service instance failure notification

Tags: azure, cloud, microservices, azure-service-fabric

How can one service get notified about another(Guest executable) service instance failure?
I have two services 
 1)stateless native service say Service A
 2)Guest executable service(Nodejs) say service B
what i want is that when any instance of service B fails(and restarted by SF) A gets a notification. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There may be a way to push notifications to your service that I'm not aware of - perhaps Azure Diagnostics supports it?  But if you can live with polling, there is a set of health monitoring REST APIs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/sfclient-index

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/service-fabric-watchdog-service/) an official example of such a [watchdog](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-watchdog-service) service.

Comment: thanks a lot but it will not help in this scenario :( .